# How can I plot function density plot Hyper-geometric /Bessel function with complex arguments?

Tags: plotting, graphics, special-functions, complex

I am interested in the plot of a function in terms of hypergeometric and Bessel
function with complex arguments, Here, it is my code,  but the result is incorrect, the solution must be defined every in the interval x,y [-30,30].
Where is the problem? How can I fix it?

```
Clear["Global`*"];  Remove["Global`*"]; 
   L = 30;

   sx[x_, y_] = 
 1/Abs[x + I y] (0. + 
    0.45 I) (BesselJ[-(1/4), 0.45  Re[Sqrt[x + I y]]^2] BesselJ[3/4, 
      0.45  Im[Sqrt[x + I y]]^2] - 
    1.` BesselJ[-(1/4), 0.45  Im[Sqrt[x + I y]]^2] BesselJ[3/4, 
      0.4  Re[Sqrt[x + I y]]^2]) Hypergeometric0F1[3/
   4, -0.051 Im[Sqrt[x + I y]]^4] Hypergeometric0F1[3/
   4, -0.051  Re[Sqrt[x + I y]]^4] (Im[Sqrt[x + I y]] Re[Sqrt[
     x + I y]])^(3/2)



outplot = 
 DensityPlot[Abs[Im[sx[x, y]]], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, 
  PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 150, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, FrameTicks -> True, 
  Exclusions -> None]
```

Comment: Where is the result incorrect? Where is the result undefined and what should it be? Just guessing, compare `Table[x=RandomReal[{-30,30}];y=RandomReal[{0,30}];Abs[Im[sx[x,y]]],{10}]` and `Table[x=RandomReal[{-30,30}];y=RandomReal[{-30,0}];Abs[Im[sx[x,y]]],{10}]`

Comment: @Bill, I tried your comment, but I do not expect a plot similar I show above,  this behavior is unexpected I have zero region ( see the figure above)

Comment: Try `DensityPlot[If[y<0,Abs[Re[sx[x,y]]],Abs[Im[sx[x,y]]]],{x,-L,L},{y,-L,L},PlotRange->Full,PlotPoints->150,ColorFunction->"Rainbow",Axes->True,AxesLabel->{x,y},FrameTicks->True,Exclusions->None]` and then very carefully look at `Table[sx[x,y],{x,-L,L,6},{y,-L,L,6}]//TableForm` to understand why your original top and bottom half of your plot looks different. Perhaps that will tell you what you really need to plot

Answer (score 1):

```
ComplexPlot[Rationalize[1/Abs[z] (0. + 
 0.45 I) (BesselJ[-(1/4), 0.45 Re[Sqrt[z]]^2] BesselJ[3/4, 
   0.45 Im[Sqrt[z]]^2] - 
 1. BesselJ[-(1/4), 0.45 Im[Sqrt[z]]^2] BesselJ[3/4, 
   0.4 Re[Sqrt[z]]^2]) Hypergeometric0F1[
3/4, -0.051 Im[Sqrt[z]]^4] Hypergeometric0F1[
3/4, -0.051 Re[Sqrt[z]]^4] (Im[Sqrt[z]] Re[Sqrt[z]])^(3/2), 0], {z, -L - I*L, L + I*L}, 
PlotPoints -> 200, WorkingPrecision -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the code presented above, I obtained the following results. It seems that for negative values the function is zero or does not exit [image]. I expect to have similar behavior as a depict a positive region.